# How to prevent creation of another dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary that I create every time someone calls a specific function. The problem is that I need the dictionary in a different spot. I've used Google but nothing can really help me on my specific problem.

Example:
I create the dict

```
private void ConnectFunc(client)
    {
     CreateDict();
    }
```

Then I try to return the created dict to use it everywhere

```
public static IDictionary<int, int> CreateDict()
  {
    Dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    return Dict;
  }
```

But now I have to make sure that the script is not creating a new dictionary again, how is that possible? (I just started learning C#, so please explain and tell me what I'm doing wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you are trying to do is the "Singleton" pattern.  "Singleton" basically means you will only ever want to have one instance of an object.

A simple example:

```
private static IDictionary<int, int> _dict = null;
public static IDictionary<int, int> CreateDict()
{
    if(_dict == null)
    {
        _dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    }
    return _dict;
}
```

One thing to keep in mind with Singletons though is thread-safety. In the above example what happens if one thread checks for null at the same time another thread checks for null.  They both find that `_dict` is null and create new Dictionary's.  Now you have two unique Dictionary's floating out there.

My favorite way to handle this comes from a [blog post](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx#lazy) Jon Skeet wrote.  This utilizes .NET 4's `Lazy<T>` type:

```
private static Lazy<IDictionary<int, int>> _lazyDict = 
        new Lazy<IDictionary<int, int>>(() => new Dictionary<int, int>());

public static IDictionary<int, int> Dict { get { return lazy.Value; } }
```

This approach is thread safe and has the benefit of being lazy loaded, plus you can eliminate the `CreateDict()` function (if all it does is create a new Dictionary).

Comment: It works pretty good, thank you (seriously u saved me a lot of time)

Comment: You're welcome!  I'd suggest reading up on common design patterns, [this](http://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns) has always been a good resource for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Singleton pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx)

It helps to familiarize yourself with basic design patterns early on, you will learn a lot.

**Edit: example**

```
public sealed class MyDictionary
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<int, int> instance = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
    // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
    static MyDictionary()
    {
    }

    private MyDictionary()
    {
    }

    public static IDictionary<int, int> Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
private void ConnectFunc(client)
{
    // get the singleton instance of your dictionary: MyDictionary.Instance
}
```

Comment: You should at least post a basic example along with the link

Comment: Added example. Would appreciate removing the downvotes.